# ESBuild and postcss are adding \ (slashes) into my css and I can't figure out why

Tags: postcss, esbuild

I have been coding along and have started to get these warning on compile now.
It seems that I have started to use "[:has" and the precompiler can't handle that. If this output is ok, I am ok with it, but if there is something that can be done to fix this, it would be great.

## My console log...

```
▲ [WARNING] Expected "]" to go with "[" [css-syntax-error]

    postcss:/home/encompass/Projects/SNAP/LOCAL/pp_alue/app/public/wp-content/themes/ppshp-modular-theme/src/assets/styles/style.pcss:9561:36:
      9561 │ .language-switcher-container[\:has\(.language-switcher-selected\[aria-expanded\%3D\%22true\%2...
           │                                     ^
           ╵                                     ]

  The unbalanced "[" is here:

    postcss:/home/encompass/Projects/SNAP/LOCAL/pp_alue/app/public/wp-content/themes/ppshp-modular-theme/src/assets/styles/style.pcss:9561:28:
      9561 │ .language-switcher-container[\:has\(.language-switcher-selected\[aria-expanded\%3D\%22true\%2...
           ╵                             ^

▲ [WARNING] Unexpected "]" [css-syntax-error]

    postcss:/home/encompass/Projects/SNAP/LOCAL/pp_alue/app/public/wp-content/themes/ppshp-modular-theme/src/assets/styles/style.pcss:9561:98:
      9561 │ ...e-switcher-container[\:has\(.language-switcher-selected\[aria-expanded\%3D\%22true\%22\]\)] {
           ╵
```

Looking into my css it does seem to be adding these "" (slashes) to the code. It is Halloween season and all, but I don't need any more slashes then I put in the code.'

## Example of the problem output...

```
.language-switcher-container[\:has\(.language-switcher-selected\[aria-expanded\%3D\%22true\%22\]\)] {
  background-color: var(--colors-primary-blue-10);
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
.language-switcher-container:has(.language-switcher-selected[aria-expanded="true"]) {
  background-color: var(--colors-primary-blue-10);
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
```

## My build configuration...

I seems that if I change the stage to 3 the errors stop, so it certainly seems to have something to do with *postCssPresetEnv*

```
const stylesPlugin = [
  postCssPlugin({
    plugins: [
      postCssPresetEnv({ stage: 1}),
      postCssEasyImport({ extensions: ['.css', '.pcss'] }),
      postCssExtendRule,
      postCssReporter(),
      url({ url: 'inline' })
    ],
  }),
];

const lint = async () => {
  try {
    const eslint = new ESLint();
    const results = await eslint.lintFiles(['src/**/*.js']);

    const formatter = await eslint.loadFormatter('stylish');
    const resultText = formatter.format(results);

    console.log(resultText);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};

const buildScripts = async () => {
  console.log('Building scripts ...');

  try {
    const timerStart = Date.now();

    // Build code
    await esbuild.build({
      entryPoints: [
        'src/endpoints/scripts.js',
        'src/endpoints/scripts.admin.js',
      ],
      format: 'iife',
      bundle: true,
      minify: true,
      outdir: 'dist/',
      plugins: [...stylesPlugin],
      sourcemap: true,
      external: ['*.svg', '*.woff', '*.css', '*.jpg', '*.png'],
    });

    const timerEnd = Date.now();
    console.log(`Done! Scripts built in ${timerEnd - timerStart} ms.`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

## Other notes:

I checked for character encoding issues, and they don't seem to be anything but UTF-8
I am using the latest node.
node v18.12.0 (npm v8.19.2)

Answer (score 1):

I eventually figure out how to at least make the error go away.

I stopped using :has() selectors as they are not compatible with firefox at the time of this post. I think eslint was bailing because of this and causes further errors down the pipeline.